# Removing multiple elements from a list

Tags: python-3.x

In this program  I have entered the elements of a list and have to find the second highest element,to achieve that I have created a separate list with the same values of original list,removed the highest element,sort in descending order and print the first element. However,the highest element is 95 and occurs twice in the list but by using the following code, only one 95 gets removed from the list

```
marks_list2 = marks_list
high = float(max(marks_list))
for j in marks_list:
    if j==high:
        marks_list2.remove(j)
marks_list2.sort(reverse=True)
print('The second highest element is:',marks_list2[0])
```

Can anyone help me rectify the code and also tell me where I went wrong with my logic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a list comprehension to reconstruct the list without the highest number: `marks_list2 = [x for x in marks_list2 if x != i]`

Comment: I know you are trying to achieve this by creating a 2nd list, but did you think of just using the in-built python `sorted()` function & indexing to get 2nd highest value in original list? i.e. `sorted(marks_list)[-2]`

Comment: @smoggers that's a good thought and is much cleaner than recreating a list. OP did mention that the highest number appears more than once. You would have to pass a `set` into the sorted function. `sorted(set(marks_list))[-2]` :)

Comment: "I have created a separate list" - No you have not.

Answer (score 0):

The python built in `set()` method removes all the repetitions.

```
marks_list = set(marks_list)
marks_list.remove(max(marks_list))
print('The second highest element is: %s' % max(marks_list))
```

Comment: Better don't call a set "list".